# Fabric.js performance with multiple large images in Chrome

Tags: image, performance, google-chrome, canvas, fabricjs

I'm working with a Fabric.js canvas.

I have a problem: when I add more objects of different high quality image (greater than 1500 * 1500), more than ten photos, the canvas slows down when moving objects in Chrome (on IE and Firefox, it's still normal).

Here's a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/psbolden/mmuvbqzc/1/) trying to add photos.

Comment: Chrome tries to keep the canvas being displayed in GPU memory, this gives an advantage until the GPU memory is full, then it has to swap the canvas in and out and can be a major slow down. You can improve performance by keeping the full res canvas off screen, and then showing a reduced res canvas for display.

Comment: I do not understand your solution. Are you have visual examples?